# Is there a way to display calendar events like the attached (looking for this type of look and feel)

Tags: calendar

Is there a way to display calendar events like the attached (looking for this type of look and feel)

[image]

Comment: Please provide more details: is this for SharePoint Online?  If yes, Modern or Classic experience?  If no, what version of SharePoint (2010 / 2013 / 2016 / 2019)?  Are you looking for an out-of-the-box / low-code / no-code solution, or is a custom coding solution acceptable?  Is there anything you have already looked into while trying to figure out how to get this look & feel?

Comment: sharepoint 2013 on prem